# How to make bootstrap dropdown work in app.component.ts

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I am new to angular 5 and I have a need to create a dropdown menu that has dynamic menu options.  I have tried several different variaitons but they all end up with the dropdown defaulting to open without the ability to close it.  I inspected the element and it is toggling the class to open but nothing happens.  Below is my code any help is appreciated.

```
template: `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Departments <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown" *ngFor="let n of departments">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="['departmentemployee', n.DepartmentId]">{{n.DepartmentName}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a [routerLink]="['employee']">Employees</a></li>
                            <li><a [routerLink]="['department']">Departments</a></li>
                            <li><a [routerLink]="['service']">Services</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
          <br /><br /><br />
          <div class='container'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>`
```

[image]

Comment: did you import the bootstrapModule in the app module?

Comment: I think this might be my issue I installed it using npm but never added it as a Component

Comment: That was it I added the following line to _Layout and it worked YAY!!!!
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />

Comment: I would suggest you add it as an import in one of your css files instead of importing it in the index,html but that works too. :)